# Vote-totals tooltip says moderator nominations are questions, on the Primary election-phase tab

Tags: bug, design, election, tooltips

On the [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13?tab=primary) tab of the 2021 Stack Overflow election, the "vote totals" tooltip says candidate nominations are questions:

[image]

Could we change that to say something like:

[image]

to be more accurate, as they're *answering* questions, not asking them?  There isn't actually a Primary phase going on in this election, but this should be fixed for future elections.

Comment: Might be related: [Election: Questionnaire history is titled "Revisions to unknown"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371773/348196)